# Creating PDF files from a ODT template

Tags: java, converting

The code is actually a TemplateBuilder.
We have 2 different templates, French and Dutch.
We need to change the template and then convert it to PDF so it can be stored in the DB later.

The main method is `createBulletins()`.

**What am I looking for?**

- I don't like the constantly reading the template from the `byte[]` for each bulletin, so if there is a possibility this could be better (with less memory consumption) I'm fully open.
- Any other suggestions/improvements.

**Framework used :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdocreport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.odt.odfdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code (Java 1.6) :**

```
public class TemplateBuilder {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TemplateBuilder.class);
    private static final int NATIONAL_NUMBER = 0;
    private static final int LANGUAGE = 2;
    private static final int NAME = 3;
    private static final int FIRST_NAME = 4;
    private static final int STREET = 5;
    private static final int ZIP = 6;
    private static final int CITY = 7;
    private static final int COUNTRY = 8;
    private static final int BIRTH_DATE = 9;
    private static final int NUMBER = 10;
    private static final int EMPLOYD_BY = 12;
    private static final int TYPE = 13;

    private byte[] templateFR;
    private byte[] templateNL;

    private RarExtractor extractor;
    private Report report;

    /**
     * The bulletin service.
     */
    @Inject
    @Named("bulletinWebService")
    private BulletinWebService bulletinService;

    /**
     * The country dao.
     */
    @Autowired
    private CountryDAO countryDAO;

    /**
     * The user helper.
     */
    @Autowired
    private BulletinUserHelper userHelper;

    private final String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());

    /**
     * Creates all the bulletins from the given templates, with data stored in the extractor.
     * 
     * @return map with bulletin info as key and byte array (file) as value.
     * @throws Exception => createPdf(Bulletin bulletin, String[] data) throws Exception so can't be more specified here.
     */
    public Map<Bulletin, byte[]> createBulletins() throws Exception {
        Map<Bulletin, byte[]> bulletins = Maps.newHashMap();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : extractor.getCsv().entrySet()) {
            Bulletin bulletin = createBulletin(entry.getValue());
            bulletins.put(bulletin, createPdf(bulletin, entry.getValue()));
            this.report.addReaded(bulletins.size());
        }
        return bulletins;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param bulletin bulletin info what need's to be filled in
     * @param data the data what must be injected into the template.
     * @return the created bulletin.
     * @throws Exception => OdfTextDocument.loadDocument throws raw exception so can't be more specified here.
     */
    private byte[] createPdf(Bulletin bulletin, String[] data) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = null;
        OdfTextDocument document = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            if ("NL".equalsIgnoreCase(data[LANGUAGE])) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(templateNL, "Nederlandstalige template is niet aanwezig.");
                Objects.requireNonNull(extractor.getBulletinTitle(), "Nederlandstalige titel is niet aanwezig.");
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(templateNL);
                bulletin.setTitle(extractor.getBulletinTitle());
            } else if ("FR".equalsIgnoreCase(data[LANGUAGE])) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(templateFR, "Franstalige template is niet aanwezig.");
                Objects.requireNonNull(extractor.getBulletinTitleFR(), "Franstalige titel is niet aanwezig.");
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(templateFR);
                bulletin.setTitle(extractor.getBulletinTitleFR());
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Kan niet vinden of het NL of FR moet zijn. Is deze op de 3de entry in de csv?");
            }
            document = OdfTextDocument.loadDocument(in);

            replace("%name%", data[NAME], document);
            replace("%firstName%", data[FIRST_NAME], document);
            replace("%street%", data[STREET], document);
            replace("%city%", data[ZIP] + " " + data[CITY], document);
            replace("%birthDate%", data[BIRTH_DATE], document);
            replace("%formNr%", data[NUMBER], document);
            replace("%sendDate%", "//TODO : TO BE CONFIRMED", document);
            replace("%employedBy%", data[EMPLOYD_BY], document);

            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, output, options);

            output.flush();
            return output.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            close(in);
            close(document);
            close(output);

        }
    }

    private Bulletin createBulletin(String[] data) throws IOException {
        Bulletin bulletin = new Bulletin();
        bulletin.setZipFileName(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(extractor.getFileName()));
        bulletin.setCreationDate(new Date());
        bulletin.setPdfFileName("N" + data[NATIONAL_NUMBER] + data[TYPE] + today + "0001");
        final Properties tokenize = parseProperties(bulletin);
        bulletin.setBulletinUser(getBulletinUser(bulletin));
        bulletin.setBulletinType(this.bulletinService
                .findBulletinType(tokenize.getProperty(BulletinTokens.DOC_TYPE)));
        updateWitchCsvInformation(data, bulletin);
        return bulletin;
    }

    /**
     * Update witch csv information.
     *
     * @param bulletin the bulletin
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    private void updateWitchCsvInformation(String[] line, Bulletin bulletin) {
        bulletin.setCountry(this.countryDAO.findOne(line[COUNTRY]));
        bulletin.setPostCode(line[ZIP]);
        bulletin.setCreationDate(new Date());
        if (bulletin.getCountry() == null) {
            report.getFilesWithoutCsvEntry().add(bulletin.getPdfFileName() + " missing country code");
            LOGGER.debug(bulletin.getZipFileName() + " for " + bulletin.getPdfFileName() + " missing country code");
        }

    }

    public void clear() {
        templateFR = null;
        templateNL = null;
        extractor = null;
        report = null;
    }

    /**
     * Search a searchfield and replace that field to the data in the document.
     * 
     * @param searchField String to search for in Document
     * @param data to be set in place of the searchfield.
     * @param document what need's a replace from searchfield to the data.
     * @throws InvalidNavigationException 
     */
    private void replace(String searchField, String data, OdfTextDocument document) throws InvalidNavigationException {
        TextNavigation search = new TextNavigation(searchField, document);
        while (search.hasNext()) {
            TextSelection item = (TextSelection) search.getCurrentItem();
            item.replaceWith(data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * safely try to close the closeable 
     * 
     * @param closeable to close.
     */
    private void close(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable!=null) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("closeable not able to close, classname : " + closeable.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the bulletin user.
     *
     * @param tokenize the tokenize
     * @return the bulletin user
     */
    private BulletinUser getBulletinUser(final Bulletin bulletin) {
        final BulletinUser x = this.userHelper.findBulletinUser(bulletin);
        if (x == null) {
            report.addNotLinked(bulletin.getPdfFileName());
        } else {
            report.addLinked(bulletin.getPdfFileName());
        }
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the properties.
     *
     * @param bulletin the bulletin
     * @return the properties
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     */
    private Properties parseProperties(Bulletin bulletin) throws IOException {
        try {
            return BulletinTokenizer.tokenize(bulletin
                    .getPdfFileName());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    public byte[] getTemplateFR() {
        return templateFR;
    }

    public void setTemplateFR(ISimpleInArchiveItem templateFR) throws IOException {
        this.templateFR = RarUtil.extract(templateFR);
    }

    public byte[] getTemplateNL() {
        return templateNL;
    }

    public void setTemplateNL(ISimpleInArchiveItem templateNL) throws IOException {
        this.templateNL = RarUtil.extract(templateNL);
    }

    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }

    public RarExtractor getExtractor() {
        return extractor;
    }

    public void setExtractor(RarExtractor extractor) {
        this.extractor = extractor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Logging multiple languages

While you do make usage of logging, you write them in sometimes in Dutch and sometimes in English.
Please try to hold to 1 language, preferable English for the logging.

### Static or not?

```
private final String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
```

It's clear that this String need's to hold todays day formatted.
The thing what you could improve is making the `SimpleDateFormat` static.
Like this you don't have an instantiation each time you create an instantiation of the `TemplateBuilder`

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
private final String today = DATE_FORMATTER.format(new Date());
```

### Known memory leak

Your code has a memory leak, not by you but by Apache.
[There is a tracker for it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ODFTOOLKIT-300) but it isn't resolved because Apache would not see it as a leak.
I came upon this because I'm the OP and the server died after approximate 250 pdf's done.

I rewrote the replace function to a simpler search, this means no looking in header and footer, and just returns the **first** Node what match the text to search :

```
    private void replace(String searchField, String data, OdfTextDocument document) throws Exception {
    Node node = findNode(searchField, document.getContentRoot().getChildNodes());
    if (node != null) {
        node.setTextContent(data);
        LOGGER.info("found node : " + searchField);
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("didn't found node : " + searchField);
    }
}

private Node findNode(String searchField, NodeList nodeList) {
    int length = nodeList.getLength();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(counter);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE && searchField.equals(node.getTextContent())) {
            return node;
        } else {
            Node child = findNode(searchField, node.getChildNodes());
            if (child != null) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Memory building up

The method `public Map<Bulletin, byte[]> createBulletins()` design isn't good

Why do you need to hold all those and return it later for saving?
What if your `getCsv().getEntrySet()` holds more then 30k entries?
*Note : This is real the real situation*

It's stacking up memory waiting to go out of memory.
Change the method to `void` or `int` if you want to return the size for a report and save every x entries. (x could also be 1). 
You have the `BulletinWebService` in the class who provides the save so use it.